# Execute bash script when running docker-compose in gitlab CI

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I've got the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image:
  name: docker/compose:1.24.1
  entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-l","-c"]

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

pytest:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd tests/
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up --abort-on-container-exit --exit-code-from pytest
```

which runs the `docker-compose.test.yml` file, which looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  pytest:
    build: ..
    command: bash -c "/wait-for-it.sh dynamodb:8000 -- && cd /tests/ && pytest -s"
  dynamodb:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    command: -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory -port 8000
```

In this case, `pytest` waits for `dynamodb` to be up and running and then runs the python tests. This works well on my machine.

However, when Gitlab CI actually runs it, I get the following error:

```
bash: /wait-for-it.sh: Permission denied
```

How to avoid this issue? Using `chmod -x`, file is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make `wait-for-it.sh` executable, in your `Dockerfile` add:

```
RUN chmod +x /path/to/wait-for-it.sh
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. Thanks for your help.